# Azure The listener for function 'Sometestfunction' was unable to start

Tags: azure, azure-functions, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

I am newbie to Azure. I am getting below error when I run my Azure function from Visual studio.

```
The listener for function 'Sometestfunction' was unable to start.
The listener for function 'Sometestfunction' was unable to start. Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common: Server encountered an internal error. Please try again after some time.
```

what may be the possible causes for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The most common problem is Storage Emulator service not start.

Try typing

```
"%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\AzureStorageEmulator.exe" status
```

in cmd to check the status.

If it returns false, enter the following command to start the Storage Emulator:

```
"%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\AzureStorageEmulator.exe" init
"%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\AzureStorageEmulator.exe" start
```

Let me know whether this can solved your problem.:)

Comment: Hello, I tried and status returns false. then tried init command and I got below error. I don't understand why it create 'AzureStorageEmulatorDb510'.

Cannot create database 'AzureStorageEmulatorDb510' : The database 'AzureStorageEmulatorDb510' does not exist. Supply a valid database name. To see available databases, use sys.databases..
Error: Cannot create database 'AzureStorageEmulatorDb510' : The database 'AzureStorageEmulatorDb510' does not exist. Supply a valid database name. To see available databases, use sys.databases..